# Proxy Service for WSO2 ESB with Carbon Studio adding throttling policy

Tags: wso2, policy, throttling, wso2-esb

I create a proxy service with Carbon Studio, this service has a Throttling policy, then deploy in WSO2 ESB but when access by administration console the throtting is disabled for this service. It's posible enable throttling in Carbon Studio?

Comment: How did you added the throttling policy? Does the policy is shown in the policy editor for the said service? This can be accessed via the link `policies`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Carbon Studio and Developer Studio does not support setting Policies via the IDE. Policy support is in Road Map for Developer Studio [1].

For that you need to use Management Console.

[1]. https://wso2.org/jira/browse/TOOLSROADMAP-1

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana